# Beforeinstallprompt not working in mobile chrome browser I was hosting from my desktop device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, progressive-web-apps

I would like to install the mobile device while hosting from the desktop.
[image]

What should I do, beforeintallprompt event is not fire in mobile chrome browser when hosting from laptop device using vite pwa

It's working in normal chrome browser form computer eg,latop,desktop